# How to avoid Android wear notification background Zoomed in and Scrolling

Tags: android, android-notifications, wear-os

I just wanted to avoid the background scrolling in the notification.

The [documentation for Android Wear](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/creating.html) specifies that the background should be 400 x 400 if it should not use parallax scrolling and a size of 640x400 if it should support parallax scrolling. The image should be put into the drawable-nodpi folder of your android app.

I tried with both the mentioned sizes but still scrolling. How to avoid both the "Zoomed in" and scrolling effect in the notification?

Comment: I noticed the same thing. Could it be a bug?

Comment: yes. It should be a bug. Is there any work around for this?